# Hello there, I'm trying to turn a 2 1D arrays into a single 2D array, but every the code is ran the output would be true and false. Vb.net console

Tags: .net, vb.net

This is inside of a procedure, getting all details from a file to an array then converting to a 2D array.

```
Sub detailTable 
    Dim detailtab(2,5),cde(5) as String
    dim pos1, sly(5) as Integer
   
   for i = 1 to 5
    Dim Length as integer = Len(filearray(i))
       for k = 1 to Length
            if Mid(filearray(i),k,1) = "∆" Then
                pos1 = k 
           
            End If
        Next
       cde(i)= Left(filearray(i),pos1-1)
       sly(i) = Right(filearray(i),(Length-pos1))
    Next
    
    Console.WriteLine("Code " & "Salary")
    Console.WriteLine(cde(4))
    for i = 1 to 2
        for j = 1 to 5
            detailtab(i,j) = cde(i)
            detailtab(i,j) = sly(i)
        Next
    Next
    
    for i = 1 to 2
        for j = 1 to 5
            Console.WriteLine(detailtab(i,j) = cde(i))
            Console.WriteLine(detailtab(i,j) = sly(i))
          
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You're assigning cde(i) to detailtab(i,j) then immediately overwriting it with sly(i).  I doubt that's actually what you want to do.  Most likely, one of those should be assigned to detailtab(1, j) and the other should be assigned to detailtab(2, j).

Comment: (Just as a side note, this looks like it's being migrated from VBA-heritage VB.  Note that in VBA, arrays are column-major, so you would normally want to reverse the indexes from how they are here in the original VBA-heritage code.  Arrays are row-major in .NET so your index order is correct here.)